# How to choose the correct resistor to change voltage?

Tags: resistors, voltage-measurement

I want to change voltage given by a little power supply that I have at home stuckd in my desk, to use it as power supply for a little DC motor.

This DC motor need an input of 3.6 volts and give me around 5.4 Watts (1500mAh).

So that power supply gives me an output of 7.62 Volts (measured with voltimeter) and 1500 mAh.

Using Ohms law "R=(V°-V¹)/I", where my itinial voltage is 7.62 and my desired voltage is 3.6, and my current required is the same 1500mAh, so my result is:

```
R = (7.62 Volts - 3.6 Volts) / 1.5 A = 2.62 Ohms
```

Then I picked a resistor of 2.6 Ω with 4 bands and 1% tolerance (red, blue, yellow, brown) and used it.

Well, I didn't test on my little motor because I don't want to waste it so I just tried to measure it using my voltimeter without link this to any led o motor and i didn't change voltage at the end. Also I was afraid to trash my motor because when I linked this resistor between positive and negative wires of my power supply it became very hot instantly.

Using this little resistor how can I test this without waste my motor and how do I know if this very resistor can handle this current?

Comment: You should be able to overload your motor somewhat for a short time.  You do that every time you start your car.  The ruling factor is overheat, which in a dense metal like copper is not instantaneous. 1 second sure won't hurt it.

Comment: i was holding it with my bear hands like a noob. Man, my finger almost melt just in time. but Im going to give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Several comments: first, your resistor will end up dropping 6 watts (4V x 1.5A)! Your little resistor will burn up very quickly! You'd need to get a 10W power resistor.

Comment: Second, using a resistor here is a very bad idea, unless you know exactly how much current your motor needs. Also, the current it requires will depend on the load. If you set the resistor for the motor under load and then remove the load, the motor will go over volt!

Comment: Actually this DC motor is from an screwing machine supplied by 3 batteries of 1.2 V 1200mAh. So it it can variable demanding current.

Comment: Not surprising, at double the voltage you get 4x the heat so 20W or so!   In normal use, given 1.5A and 4V that'll be 6 watts of heat dissipation, and you don't want to run a resistor at its limits, as they get rather hot.  I aim for 2-4x the needed wattage, so a 12-25W resistor.   If you have 4 resistors of the right value, you can connect them in series-parallel for the same value at 4x the wattage.  A 3x3 series-parallel array also works for 9x the wattage.

Comment: @DoxyLover you have to keep an eye on it, but it can work in certain applications.  Motors are more flexible than you'd think.